# Mouse clicks sometimes not working

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I have USB Razer mouse. Sometimes when I want to click something within apps, it does not register my click. However, moving mouse works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unity --replace` fixes the problem

Comment: In my case, clicking on the launcher worked, but not in applications. This command (launched from `Alt+F2`) helped, but killed Chromium and Spotify.

Comment: For me it closed everything and I had to log in again.

Comment: this worked at the time. are you using other version than 14.04?

Comment: What if it's Gnome (17.10)?

Comment: @AttilaFulop then this will not work at all because `unity` is Unity desktop environment specific

Comment: @Kunok that's correct :)